# IIS token based security, ssl certificate and https, proxy

Tags: iis, ssl, proxy, https, token

I have developed a new web service.   Now, I need to deal with security issue as we are intending to make it a secure service.

In order to set up SSL and https, I need to obtain and install an SSL certificate.  Who is the certificate authority?

Do you know how to go about with this?

Are there concise articles on this?

Regards.

David

Answer (score 0):

You can choose where you buy your SSL certificate.
e.g. [Verisign](http://www.verisign.com).

They [provide information](https://knowledge.verisign.com/support/ssl-certificates-support/index?page=content&id=AR212&actp=LIST) on how to install SSL certificated on your IIS webserver.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

hey i would suggest you to start with a free development certificate (which you can create yourself)

once you are done with all your development and debugging, you can contact verisign or other ca's for a real one

its very easy to create a free development certificate for testing. i had blogged about it [here](http://codeforeternity.com/blogs/technology/archive/2008/02/15/creating-self-signed-ssl-certificates-on-iis-6-0-and-windows-server-2003.aspx)